# Giving the wrong records when used datetime parameter in MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working MS-Access 2007 DB .

I am trying to write the query for the Datetime, I want to get records between 14 December and 16 December so I write the bellow query.

```
SELECT * FROM Expense WHERE CreatedDate > #14-Dec-15# and CreatedDate < #16-Dec-15#
```

( I have to use the two dates for the query.)

But It returning the records having CreatedDate is 14 December...
Whats wrong with the query ?

[image]

Comment: the `createdDate` has a `time` part too.

Comment: Yes, Still I want to get the only 15 Dec records, how to consider only date not the time...

Comment: Maybe `CDATE(INT(CreatedDate)) > #14-Dec-15#`

Comment: If so, it should be `INT(CreatedDate) > #2015/12/14#` as Int doesn't change data type, but the method would leave an index on `CreatedDate` in the dark. Not that it would mean much for a small table, though.

Comment: I'm going to have a look at the meaning of the # a bit further as while testing - `INT(Created) = #01/02/2013#` returns nothing `CDATE(INT(Created)) = #01/02/2013#` returns `Invalid Use  of Null` (can't turn a Null into a date) and `CDATE(INT(NZ(Created,0))) = #01/02/2013#' returns hundreds of records with values like `02/01/2013 06:48:34`.  Agreed that it ruins any index on the Created field :)

Comment: @Gustav Thanks a lot it works...

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook thanks a lot it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks A Lot guys for your help...

I finally ended with the solution given by Darren Bartrup-Cook and Gustav ....

My previous query was....

```
SELECT * FROM Expense WHERE CreatedDate > #14-Dec-15# and CreatedDate < #16-Dec-15#
```

And the New working query is...

```
SELECT * FROM Expense WHERE CDATE(INT(CreatedDate)) > #14-Dec-15# and CDATE(INT(CreatedDate)) < #16-Dec-15#
```

Comment: Does this query give you what you want?  `SELECT * FROM Expense WHERE CreatedDate >= #2015-12-15# and CreatedDate < #2015-12-16#;`

Comment: Yes...Exactly what I want... I used > not the >=

Comment: OK.  From the comments, you can see there was a fair amount of confusion about exactly what you wanted.  I restored my answer because I think it has what you want plus additional information you may find useful.

Answer (score 2):

As @vkp mentions in the comments, there is a `time` part to a date as well. If it is not defined it defaults to midnight (`00:00:00`). As `14-dec-2015 6:46:56` is after `14-dec-2015 00:00:00` it is included in the result set. You can use `>= 15-dec-15` to get around this, as it will also include records from 15-dec-2015. Same goes for the end date.

Comment: Understand, can I use  (00:00:00). in my query ? Or where should I use     > 15-dec-15

Comment: You can use the time component if you like, but I would personally use `>= #15-dec-15#`, Use it in place of `> #14-Dec-15#`. (Not very familiar with access, the `#` are apparently necessary...)

Comment: I beg your pardon, your were right... I just delete all my comments for cleaning up. You might want to do the same. Thx and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You must inlcude the time in your thinking:

> EDIT: I wrote this with the misunderstanding, that you **wanted** to
>   include data rows from 14th to 16th of Dec (three full days).

If you'd write `<#17-Dec-15#` it would be the full 16th. Or you'd have to write `<=#16-Dec-15 23:59:59#`.

A DateTime on the 16th of December with a TimePart of let's say 12:30 is bigger than #16-Dec-15#...

Just some backgorund: In Ms-Access a DateTime is stored as a day's number and a fraction part for the time. `0.5` is midday, `0.25` is 6 in the morning...

Comparing DateTime values means to compare Double-values in reality.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want only records from Dec 15th regardless of the time of day stored in `CreatedDate`.  If so, this query should give you what you want with excellent performance assuming an index on `CreatedDate` ...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Expense
WHERE CreatedDate >= #2015-12-15# and CreatedDate < #2015-12-16#;
```

Beware of applying functions to your target field in the `WHERE` criterion ... such as `CDATE(INT(CreatedDate))`.  Although logically correct, it would force a full table scan.  That might not be a problem if your `Expense` table contains only a few rows.  But for a huge table, you really should try to avoid a full table scan.

Comment: I beg your pardon, you were right :-) happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Just add one day to your end date and exclude this:

```
SELECT * FROM Expense WHERE CreatedDate >= #2015/12/14# AND CreatedDate < #2015/12/17#
```

Comment: Why are you repeating my answer?

Comment: It contains literal months which should be avoided if possible and it is here.

Comment: When you see a trap, it is polite to guide people around it.

Comment: Well, OK, but wasn't that a comment though? Nvm, happy coding :-)

Comment: This will not help, records will return values form 14 Dec to 17 dec as well...your previous suggestion in comment was helpful...

Comment: @Shnugo I know, but thanks. "@user1650894" Why do you think so? That filter can't return dates of the 17th.